# Three JS rendering from one buffer into itself

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, glsl, webgl

I really hope you can help me with this question, as it confusses me since some time:

I have a three js context.
There i create a custom material and let it render into a texture.

`

```
/* Texture render environment */
    fbo_renderer_scene = new THREE.Scene();
    fbo_renderer_ripple_update_scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var fbo_texture_light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.5);
    fbo_texture_light.position.set(0.0, 0.0, -1.0).normalize();
    fbo_renderer_scene.add(fbo_texture_light);
    fbo_renderer_ripple_update_scene.add(fbo_texture_light);

    ripple_texture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, render_target_params);
    ripple_update_texture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, render_target_params);

    ripple_material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
    {

        uniforms: 
        {
            texture1: { type: "t", value: bottom_plane_texture},
        },

        vertexShader: document.getElementById('drop_vert_shader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('drop_frag_shader').textContent,

        depthWrite: false
    });


    fbo_renderer_camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(width / -2.0, width / 2.0, height / 2.0, height / -2.0, -10000, 10000);
    var texture_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(bottom_plane_geometry, ripple_material);
    fbo_renderer_scene.add(texture_mesh);
    renderer.render(fbo_renderer_scene, fbo_renderer_camera, ripple_texture, true);
```

Ok fine now i have everything in ripple_texture

Now there is another shader which should update the ripple shape on Animate() gets called.

And of course it should render the result into the ripple_texture again:

```
/* Texture render environment */
fbo_renderer_scene = new THREE.Scene();
fbo_renderer_ripple_update_scene = new THREE.Scene();
var fbo_texture_light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.5);
fbo_texture_light.position.set(0.0, 0.0, -1.0).normalize();
fbo_renderer_scene.add(fbo_texture_light);
fbo_renderer_ripple_update_scene.add(fbo_texture_light);

ripple_texture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, render_target_params);
ripple_update_texture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, render_target_params);

ripple_material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
{

    uniforms: 
    {
        texture1: { type: "t", value: bottom_plane_texture},
    },

    vertexShader: document.getElementById('drop_vert_shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('drop_frag_shader').textContent,

    depthWrite: false
});


fbo_renderer_camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(width / -2.0, width / 2.0, height / 2.0, height / -2.0, -10000, 10000);
var texture_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(bottom_plane_geometry, ripple_material);
fbo_renderer_scene.add(texture_mesh);
renderer.render(fbo_renderer_scene, fbo_renderer_camera, ripple_texture, true);
```

But everytime i try to do this Chromium reports this:

> WebGLRenderingContext-0x3d022469aa80]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION :
>   glDrawElements: Source and destination textures of the draw are the
>   same.

Firefox just shows a black canvas.

I guess this might be a timing issue but im not sure and have no clue how to bypass this, since three js has no callback for render.

Answer (score 3):

It's telling you what's wrong:

> WebGLRenderingContext-0x3d022469aa80]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.

You can't read and render to the same texture at once because your render operations will trample the texture data you're reading from during rendering, giving you garbage output.

You'll need to have another texture that you render into that isn't the same as the one you're reading from.